# Crash in Intent.putExtra() on some samsung devices

Tags: android, android-intent, samsung-mobile

From my app, I'm opening the Documents with [ACTION_GET_CONTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) to get a video. I'm getting a Uri in onActivityResult() and using that to create a new activity in my app. This works generally well except on some samsung devices, at least galaxy S5 and galaxy S5 mini where it crashes in Intent.putExtra() with a NullPointerException.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == 1 && intent != null && intent.getData() != null) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);

        Uri uri = intent.getData()
        /**
         * Galaxy S5 will crash here
         */
        i.putExtra("uri", uri);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong ? The uri itself is not null, if I log it, I get:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A459
```

The logs I get are:

```
2016-02-04 11:05:09.120 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
2016-02-04 11:05:09.120 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at android.content.Intent.putExtra(Intent.java:6471)
2016-02-04 11:05:09.120 ERROR:  AndroidRuntime : at com.mbonnin.app.ui.activity.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:337)
```

Comment: There isn't any `putExtra` method in `Intent` which accepts `Uri`, how does you code work on other phones should be the concern. Try to send the data as `String` as suggested by @anshuljain

Comment: @Rohit5k2 but there is one that accepts a `Parcelable` which `Uri` implements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("uri",uri.toString());
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

In the second activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String uri  = bundle.getString("uri");
```

Comment: This works well, thanks ! Sounds really fishy though. Any idea why using a Parcelable won't work ?

Comment: @mbonnin: is it working well for all devices except samsung s5?

Comment: so far, nexus 7, nexus 5, nexus 6, nexus 5X, nexus 6P seem ok. Samsung S5 and S5 mini crash. Did not get the opportunity to test more though.